# Inserir um espaço vazio entre uma concatenação de strings em C, sem a biblioteca string.h

Tags: c, codeblocks

Estou implementando esse código com objetivo de receber duas strings e compará-las, se as duas strings forem diferentes eu concateno as duas em um vetor, porém eu desejo adicionar um espaço em branco entra elas.

Como posso realizar essa tarefa sem utilizar a biblioteca string.h?

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    char aux;
    char nome[10];
    char sobreNome[10];
    char concatNome[20];

    printf("Digite o seu primeiro nome: \n");
    gets(nome);

    printf("Digite o seu sobrenome: \n");
    gets(sobreNome);

     /*Este for compara os valores(caracteres) índice por 
        índice e avalia se o tamanho dos vetores nome e 
        sobrenome são iguais.*/
    for(i=0; nome[i]==sobreNome[i] && nome[i]!= '\0' && 
          sobreNome[i]!= '\0' && i<sizeof(nome) && 
          i<sizeof(sobreNome); i++);

    if(nome[i]=='\0' && sobreNome[i]=='\0'){

        printf("Os nomes são iguais\n");
    }else{
        /*Este for copia a string armazenada no vetor nome 
           e armazena no vetor concatNome*/
        for(j=0;j<sizeof(concatNome)&&nome[j]!='\0'; j++){

            aux = nome[j];
            concatNome[j] = aux;
        }
    /*Esse for é responsável por concatenar a string do vetor sobreNome ao 
    vetor concatNome*/            
    for(k=0;j<sizeof(concatNome)&&sobreNome[k]!='\0'
    &&concatNome[j]!='\0';k++, j++){

            aux = sobreNome[k];
            concatNome[j] = aux;
        }
        concatNome[j]='\0';
        printf("Nome e sobrenome concatenados : %s\n", concatNome);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ola Kelion, bem vindo ao stackoverflow. :) Tu poderia por favor adicionar comentarios no teu codigo, explicando em cada parte, o que ele esta fazendo? Em especial, o que cada um dos 3 comandos `for` fazem. Isto vai te ajudar a entender melhor o teu codigo, e fica mais facil de te explicar a resposta ao que tu esta pedindo. ^_^

Comment: Note que você definiu suas strings com tamanho fixo e portanto o operador sizeof retornará a quantidade de bytes alocados, 10 para nome e sobreNome e 20 para concatNome o que, me parece não é o que está esperando em seus loops, a não ser que você sempre forneça nomes e sobrenomes com exatamente 10 caracteres mas, neste caso, estará ultrapassando a área locada pois será automaticamente inserido o caractere terminador '\0'. Sugestão: trabalhe considerando apenas o caractere terminador '\0 para controlar a cópia dos caracteres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas a concatenação pode ser feita da seguinte forma (considere o comentário acima):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, k;
    char aux;
    char nome[10];
    char sobreNome[10];
    char concatNome[20];

    printf("Digite o seu primeiro nome: \n");
    gets(nome); /* melhor seria utilizar fgets */

    printf("Digite o seu sobrenome: \n");
    gets(sobreNome); /* melhor seria utilizar fgets */

    i=0;
    j=0;
    while (nome[i] != '\0')
        concatNome[j++] = nome[i++];
    concatNome[j++] = ' ';
    i=0;
    while (sobreNome[i] != '\0')
        concatNome[j++] = sobreNome[i++];
    concatNome[j]='\0';
    printf("Nome e sobrenome concatenados : %s\n", concatNome);
    return 0;
}
```

Também estou interpretando "espaço vazio" como o caractere espaço (0X20) e não o caractere nulo (0X00).

Comment: No caso eu desejo inserir o caractere espaço (0x20) entre a string do vetor nome e a string do vetor sobreNome. ex.: "João"+" "+"Silva".

Comment: É exatamente o que faz o comando: concatNome[j++] = ' ';

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar a função **strcat** da biblioteca **string.h**

```
strcpy (concatNome, nome); // Adiciona a string nome para a string de concatenação
strcat (concatNome," ");   // Concatena o espaço em branco na string
strcat (concatNome, sobreNome); // Concatena o sobrenome
```

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar amigo, contudo infelizmente nesse exemplo não posso usar a biblioteca string.h, foi um "desafio" que o meu professor propôs. Mas agradeço muito, bom saber que existem outras maneiras mais simples.